# Return String from Map in collection firebase & Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to return the strings in this map in a collection. I would like to return all strings that are marked as true but I am not sure how to do that. Attached is a screenshot of my firebase setup. Any help would be much appreciated. [image]

Comment: With this data structure you can only get the entire `fourthQuestion` field as map and filter it on the client side.

Comment: You can change `fourthQuestion` to type `List` and only put in the strings that are true in it. So, when you fetch `fourthQuestion`, you fetch all strings that are true.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to get the snapshots, and each document has only one question, which is what you have pictured:

```
Map<String, Map<String, bool>> questions = snapshot.data();

questions.forEach((question, options) {
  options.forEach((option, value) {
    if (value) {return option;}
  });
});
```

question is fourthQuestion.

option is each possible answer? 1-2, 13 or more etc.

and value is t/f

Comment: Thank you! Yes, getting the snapshots is no issue. I do have 6 different questions within the document though. I can’t share the info in the other questions but they are structured the same way. How would that affect your answer? My apologies, the person who worked on this feature before me structured it in a confusing way for me to figure out how to do this.

Comment: I assumed you getting a documentsnapshot, in which case, questions will iterate every question within that doc.  instead of returning the option, you could populate it in a list, or whatever....but you're looking at each question there.